# Even Odd or Neither

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

If f(x) and g(x) are both even functions, is f + g even? If f(x) and g(x) are both odd functions, is f + g odd? What if f(x) is even and g(x) is odd?

Now intuitively I get that for the first one, the resulting answer will be EVEN

For second one it will be ODD

And for the last one it will be  Neither.

But I don't know how to justify that... it just came to me intuitively, Can someone show me a way through al-gebra to prove my claim.

Comment: use the fact (f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x) and the definition of odd/even function :-)

Comment: The easiest way to prove the 3rd one is to use an example.  $f(x)=1$ and $g(x)=x$.  You can prove that $h(x)=x+1$ is neither odd nor even by comparing with $h(-x)$.

Answer (score 3):

For the first two, just use the definition of even and odd to draw the desired conclusion. You will not be able to justify your conclusion on the last one. The sum of an even function and an odd function maybe even, odd, both, or neither. Bear in mind that the constant 0 function is both even and odd, as that should help you construct explicit examples for each of the four possibilities. For example, consider $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=x^3.$ Then $f$ is even and $g$ is odd, but $$(f+g)(-1)=0\neq2=(f+g)(1)$$ and $$(f+g)(-1)=0\neq-2=-(f+g)(1),$$ so $f+g$ is neither even nor odd. I leave the other three cases to you.

Comment: oh okay I see.. so if f(x) was the zero function the last problem will be an odd function.... but if g(x) was the zero function it would be an even?

Comment: Precisely correct!

Comment: Here's a corrected version of an earlier comment. We can say a little bit more. Assuming that $f$ and $g$ are functions $E\to\Bbb R$ for some $E\subseteq\Bbb R,$ where $f$ is even and $g$ is odd, then (1) $f+g$ is even if and only if $g(x)=0$ for all $x\in E\setminus\{0\}$, and (2) $f+g$ is odd if and only if $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in E\setminus\{0\}.$ If we further assume that $0\in E$ and that $f$ and $g$ are continuous at $x=0,$ then (1) $f+g$ is even if and only if $g$ is the constant $0$ function on $E$, and (2) $f+g$ is odd if and only if $f$ is the constant $0$ function on $E.$

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be even functions. Then we have
$$ (f+g)(-x) = f(-x) + g(-x) = f(x)+g(x) = (f+g)(x) $$

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be odd functions. Then we have
$$ (f+g)(-x) = f(-x)+g(-x) = -f(x) -g(x) = -(f+g)(x) $$

Let $f(x)$ be an even function and $g(x)$ be an odd function. Then we have
$$ (f+g)(-x) = f(-x)+g(-x) = f(x) - g(x) = (f-g)(x) $$
We can't say whether $f-g$ is even or odd.

Comment: This only transforms the 3rd problem to an equivalent intuition.

Comment: Oh okay that makes sence... as we are assuming here... okay what you did. Alright thanks !

Comment: @ex0du5.. what do you mean?

Comment: I suspect that ex0du5 means that nothing has actually been shown by your manipulations in the third case.

Comment: @CameronBuie.. really? but it shows that  (f-g)(x) is nether -(f+g)(x)  nor is it  (f+g)(x).... hence neither even nor odd ?

Comment: @Naqvi: it doesn't show that.  There are no inequalities there at all.  Nor is that even true.  It is very possible that it could be even or odd.  There are possibly two confusing uses of "neither" here - a function may be "neither" even nor odd, or you may be unable to "neither" prove it even or prove it odd without more information.  All you have here is the latter.  You can prove the latter by giving an example of the former.  Or you can give two examples, one even and one odd, to show that neither is provable with the info.